# Is there a "framerate" for the universe?

Tags: kinematics, spacetime, time

I've been wondering this for quite some time.  I just can't wrap my head around the idea of truly continuous time.  If time is truly infinitely divisible, then how can any object in the universe move?  It seems to me that if time is continuous then time would not physically make sense.  Time would be unable to "flow" because in order to get from one moment of time to another, it would have to pass through an infinite amount of time to reach second moment.

Quick example:  Say a ball rolls off the table and bounces on the floor.  Now, say we look at two time points while the ball is falling that are 1x10^-100 seconds apart.  If time is truly continuous, then these points have an infinite amount of points in between them.  Thus, to move from point a to point b, an infinite amount of time would have to pass.  This is what I can't wrap my head around.

I realize that just because I can't wrap my head around it doesn't mean my idea must be right.  To me, though, it doesn't seem to make sense that time can truly be absolutely continuous.  Can I get some answers here?  Is there any significant research as to whether or not time is discrete or continuous?  I'd be more than happy to read an explanation as to why my scenario above is incorrect, it would sure rest my mind on the subject.

As I said, I realize that just because I can't wrap my head around this doesn't mean that time must be discrete.  I'm just, well, having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: This is (yet another) question on [Zeno's paradoxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes). See the article I've linked or [search this site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=zeno+paradox) for more.

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks, sorry for the duplicate.  I'm new here :P